# How do you launch an activity from a widget and handle the response in MainActivity?

Tags: android

I have an app which has 2 activities- MainActivity and Activity2. MainActivity starts Activity2 by calling `startActivityForResult` and implements `onActivityResult` to handle the result. This works perfectly well.

I have made a widget that starts Activity2 directly. How do I then invoke `onActivityResult` on MainActivity to handle the result? I can call `startActivity(intent, MainActivity.Class)` from Activity2 to create a new instance of MainActivity, but I would like to use the existing instance and to call its method `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something similar by changing the launchmode of MainActivity to `singleTask` and handling it in `onNewIntent`.